# undefined ngrx state on app start, no StoreModule.forRoot() set up

Tags: angular, undefined, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I am using `redux` in Angular using `ngrx` .but i am getting `undefined` value initially why

here is my code **don't run this on chrome** (issue in stackblitz in chrome browser ) Please use other browser.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sz7rul?file=src%2Fapp%2Findex.ts

```
const getProductFeatureState =createFeatureSelector<fromProduct.ProductState>('productFeature')

export const getProducts = createSelector(
  getProductFeatureState,
  state => {

    console.log(state);
    return state.products
  }
);
```

I am printing my state it is giving me `undefined` .please help .Inspect the element and see the error

```
preview-fe7237b13d780dbf847da.js:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'products' of undefined
    at eval (VM2486 index.ts:15)
    at eval (selector.js:84)
    at memoized (selector.js:34)
    at defaultStateFn (selector.js:58)
    at eval (selector.js:87)
    at MapSubscriber.memoized [as project] (selector.js:34)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.ts:78)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:102)
    at State.BehaviorSubject._subscribe (BehaviorSubject.ts:24)
    at State.Observable._trySubscribe
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting up the `NgRx` wrongly. In the `AppModule`, use have to use `StoreModule.forRoot(...)`. In the feature module, you will use `StoreModule.forFeature(...)`
For your example to work, I fixed it here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8tuwu8?file=src/app/index.ts

See example app here: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/example-app

Comment: i don't have feature module so I am using StoreModule.forRoot(...)

Comment: there is no ngmodule of product .

Comment: @user5711656 yes, that's why the set up is wrong, the `StoreModule.forRoot(...)` require a lot more set up than the `StoreModule.forFeature(...)`. Here is how to set it up: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/example-app/app/reducers/index.ts

Comment: @user5711656 I updated my answer, added how to set up it correctly for `StoreModule.forRoot()`

Answer (score -1):

You're creating a `featureSelector` without any feature modules loaded in the store (no `StoreModule.forFeature('products', reducer)` in your code)

try this in your index.ts selector code:

```
export const getProducts = (state: fromProduct.ProductState) => state.products;
```

Comment: still not working https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sz7rul?file=src%2Fapp%2Findex.ts